# Как с помощью ansible клонировать не весь репозиторий из git, а только некоторые директории?

Tags: git, ansible

Всем привет.
Хочу с git клонировать себе на сервер пару директорий с помощью ansible.
Но не  могу найти информацию как это сделать.
Сейчас можно клонировать только весь репозиторий и то, подвисает и потом ничего не копирует.

Насколько мне известно, без скачивания репозитория локально, копирование сделать нельзя.

```
- name: clone from git
  git:
    repo: 'https://git**/test.git'
    dest: "/data/ansible/files/redis/nginx"
    version: master
```

Comment: Попробуй на .sh написать скрипт который будет копировать нужные тебе данные после запуска git clone

Comment: Тебе вот это надо, но только на ansible? https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-can-I-download-a-specific-folder-from-a-GitHub-repo/td-p/88

Comment: Это интересно о каком размере репы идет реч и что именно виснет? Какая скорость подлючения и на чем распаковка идет. Ансибл сам посебе ресурсный инструмент потребляющий мнго памяти и вызывающий большой прирост I/O

Answer (score 1):

если вам нужна только часть файлов, то, скорее всего, вам само хранилище и не требуется.

и можно скачать только архив с файлами/каталогами, из которого распаковать лишь то, что нужно. архив умеют формировать все распространённые системы управления хранилищами (*github, gitlab, bitbucket* и т.д. и т.п.), не говоря уж про саму программу *git* (`$ man git-archive`).

---

#### пример.

из хранилища https://github.com/ansible/ansible возьмём архив с файлами по указателю `devel` (это у них указатель по умолчанию) и распакуем из него только каталоги `bin` и `docs`:

```
$ curl https://github.com/ansible/ansible/archive/devel.tar.gz | \
  tar -xz ansible-devel/docs ansible-devel/bin
```

в текущем каталге появился каталог `ansible-devel` и в нём под-каталоги `bin` и `docs` (с содержимым, естественно):

```
$ tree -L 1 ansible-devel/
ansible-devel/
├── bin
└── docs
```

если вас не устраивает наличие каталога `ansible-devel`, и нужно, чтобы под-каталоги `bin` и `docs` находились прямо в текущем каталоге, добавьте программе *tar* опцию `--strip=1` (`1` — это количество уровней вложенности, которые надо пропустить):

```
$ curl https://github.com/ansible/ansible/archive/devel.tar.gz | \
  tar -xz --strip=1 ansible-devel/docs ansible-devel/bin
```

тогда текущий каталог будет выглядеть так:

```
$ tree -L 1 .
.
├── bin
└── docs
```

p.s. опцией `-C каталог` можно указать программе *tar* другое место для распаковки (вместо текущего каталога).